# How to delete MongoDB duplicates documents in buffer collection

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using PHP + Mongo 3.2.9 for my project.

This project hosts millions of documents with many new recording everyday.
To optimize my database, I use a buffer collection that store recording ids to only save new documents in another collection.

To do so I try to develop a optimized script that is deleting duplicate recording, taking care to delete documents with less fields.

The buffer collection (without the _id) :

```
[
{
    label : "red",
    added : true
},
{
    label : "yellow",
    added : true
},
{
    label : "pink"
},
{
    label : "blue"
},
{
    label : "green"
},
{
    label : "grey"
},
{
    label : "pink",
    added : true
},
{
    label : "blue",
    added : true
},
{
    label : "green"
},
{
    label : "red"
},
{
    label : "blue"
}
]
```

Taking the example above :
Here a collection of colors. Some have the status "added", some other not.
I would like a script that let only one document for each color, and especially the one with "added : true" field if exists.

Here how the result should be :

```
[
{
    label : "red",
    added : true
},
{
    label : "yellow",
    added : true
},
{
    label : "green"
},
{
    label : "grey"
},
{
    label : "pink",
    added : true
},
{
    label : "blue",
    added : true
}
]
```

I imagined to process with 2 php scripts :

```
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017/?w=0');

// script 1  
$filter = ['added' => [ '$exists' => true ]];

$q = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
$rows = $m->executeQuery('db.buffer', $q);

forEach ($rows as $r) {

    $b = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

    $f = [ 'label' => $r->label, 'added' => [ '$exists' => false ] ];

    $b->delete($f);

    if (count($b) > 0) {
        $result = $m->executeBulkWrite('db.buffer', $b);
    }
}

// script 2:
$filter = ['added' => [ '$exists' => false ]];

$q = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
$rows = $m->executeQuery('db.buffer', $q);

forEach ($rows as $r) {

    $b = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

    $f = [ '_id' => [ '$gt' => $r->_id ], 'label' => $r->label];

    $b->delete($f);

    if (count($b) > 0) {
        $result = $m->executeBulkWrite('db.buffer', $b);
    }   
}
```

But in fact that way is too long (especially the second script) and I got Fatal error because de processing time was over.

I'm sure there is a better way to improve the process.

Thanks for helping me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you consider using unique index for color field?

Comment: Do you mean adding another index field in each document ?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-unique/